# Reordering xml element by script

Tags: python, xml, xslt, lxml

I have a lot of XML files describing some documents. Unfortunately, some of them contain error with respect to the ordering of pages. After determining the correct order (by hand, probably) I want to reorder the pages using a script. Python lxml is the preferred type of script, but other solutions working in a standard Linux environment are welcome, too.

Input file looks like:

```
<text>
  <page>content of page 2</page>
  <page>content of page 3</page>
  <page>content of page 1</page>
</text>
```

Output file looks like:

```
<text>
  <page>content of page 1</page>
  <page>content of page 2</page>
  <page>content of page 3</page>
</text>
```

Note: Instead of reordering the elements reordering the //text() of the elements is sufficient, too, since all elements have the same name and don't carry attributes.

Comment: You have tagged this XSLT. Are you interested in an XSLT solution? If yes, please explain how you intend to input the correct order.

Comment: For the moment being, hard-coding the wanted order is good enough. Giving the target permutation as a tupel or a list (for the example above it would be (2,3,1) ) is an option for a more advanced script.

Comment: Didn't you mean (3,1,2)?

Comment: My thinking in the tupel design was: The first element goes to position 2, the second to position 3, and the third to position 1. The tupel contains the final positions. The initial positions aren't noted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The first element goes to position 2, the second to position 3, and
>   the third to position 1.

That's a little more difficult to implement in XSLT (esp. in XSLT 1.0), but assuming you are using the libxslt processor, you can take advantage of the EXSLT str:tokenize extension function to simplify the matter:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:str="http://exslt.org/strings"
extension-element-prefixes="str">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:param name="order">2,3,1</xsl:param>

<xsl:template match="/">
    <text>
        <xsl:for-each select="text/page">
            <xsl:sort select="str:tokenize($order, ',')[count(current()/preceding-sibling::page) + 1]" data-type="number" order="ascending"/>
            <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </text>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

As you can see, you can either hard-code the order in the stylesheet, or pass it as a parameter at runtime.